# How to supply parameters to sql server procedure

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, parameters, procedure

I'm currently executing this code from ms access which calls a stored procedure from SQL server to create a temporary table and export the data in that table directly to excel workbook. I'm now looking to have two date fields from my form to be parameters (dateOpen, dateClose) for this procedure. How would I do this?

```
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd1 As New ADODB.Command
Dim cmd2 As New ADODB.Command
Dim cmd3 As New ADODB.Command

With cmd1
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.connection
    .CommandText = "usp_tbl_close"
End With
Set rst = cmd1.Execute
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "dbo.close", "C:\Documents\testio3.xls", True, "close"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the create and append parameter methods in ADO DB.

Here is a link to a [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that should help.

Answer (score 0):

try this
With cmd1
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.connection
    .CommandText = "usp_tbl_close"
    .CommandType = 4
    .Parameters("@paramname1") = paramvalue1
    .Parameters("@paramname2") = paramvalue2
    .execute

End With